# Unable to add points to Leaflet.js heatmap

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using Leaflet.js and Leaflet.heat. When I add points I get "unable to get property lat of undefined or null reference". When I print the value of point in console and paste it in the code, it works. What am I doing wrong?

```js
setTimeout(function () {
                 if (i >= num_frames) {
                     return;
                 }
        
                 try {
                    
                     var points = "[" + array_all_snapshot[i] + "]";
                     console.log(points);
                     var points = array_all_snapshot[i];
                     var heat = L.heatLayer(points, {
                         maxZoom: 10
                     })
                         .addTo(map);
              

                 }
                 catch (e) {
                     console.log(array_all_snapshot[i]);
                     console.log(e.toString());


                 }


                 i += 1;
                 requestAnimationFrame(function () { repeatOften(i); });

             }, 11
        );
```

Comment: Where is `i`, `array_all_snapshot` defined for example?

Comment: They are outside the function. Sorry I did not clarify the code. I fixed the issue.  I had to JSON.parse() the points. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake. I had to JSON.parse() the points.